# Detect Life Enchantment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been playing Skyrim for a while now and have yet to see a detect life enchantment in shops or in  random loot. just wondering if there is actually a detect life enchantment as it was my favorite in oblivion.

Comment: I would check the wiki, but I do know there's a shout, and probably a spell

Comment: Yeah i have the spell but it uses a lot of magicka.

Comment: Aura Whisper is the name of the shout. And it is excellent when you're trying to stay sneaky!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no way to enchant detect life onto an item, but there is a spell you can cast that constantly drains magika while you are using it.  There's always the chance a modder will add it in at some point.

Comment: More than a chance ;)

Comment: ugh yeah i could probably make the mod my self it would have just been better if it was in game, i loved that enchantment in oblivion :(

Answer (score -3):

The Skyrim devs didn't really implement "detect *" into the engine.  Instead they cut corners and created a area of effect attack that leaves a glow afterwards.  Consequentially you actually have to script into the game your own detection mechanism from the ground up.  It has to attack every creature conditionally depending on its reaction to player.

Comment: Do you have source to back up your claim?